# my chat server does not send messages to the client

Tags: java, multithreading

i have this code to do chatting

but it did not work , but somebody told me that i should use byte array and a string but i did not understand i hope you can help me to fix this problem , this code belongs to the server...

```
 public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket= new ServerSocket(44444);//inside there is the port mumber which will be gain later from firstscreen
        ClientSocket= ServerSocket.accept();
        OUT=  new ObjectOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
        IN=new ObjectInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
        while (true){
            Object input =IN.readObject();
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"Client:"+(String)input+"\n");//update the textarea
        }//loop end

    }catch (IOException e){
        //joptionpane
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //joptionpane
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}//end of try

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Send")|| e.getSource() instanceof JTextField){
        try {
            if(textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            OUT.writeObject(textField.getText());
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"Assistant:"+textField.getText()+"\n");}    
        }
        catch (IOException c){
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you understand that you are only letting just a SINGLE client connect to the server, since there cannot happen any other `serverSocket.accept()`

First, you are only sending the information if the textfield text is empty at `if(textField.getText().isEmpty())` which is quite a nonsense, otherwise there is no call to send through socket any data.

Apart from this, I do not see the code for the actionPerformed block, which I assume you have coded it before with a JButton or so and implementing the `jbutton.addActionListener()`

Also, I hope ClientSocket is a class of your own, because a client is represented as a Socket, not ClientSocket.

On the other hand, I would suggest the following API [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) and forget about needing to cast the string into bytes or otherways, with the help of DataInput and DataOutputStreams.

The code would be left as:

```
public void run() {
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket= new ServerSocket(44444);//inside there is the port mumber which will be gain later from firstscreen
    Socket clientSocket= serverSocket.accept();
    DataOutputStream OUT =  new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream IN = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    while (true){
        String input = IN.readUTF();
        textArea.append(input+"\n"); //update the textarea
    }//loop end

}catch (IOException e){
    //joptionpane
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    //joptionpane
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
}//end of try



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Send")|| e.getSource() instanceof JTextField) {
    try {
        if(!textField.getText().isEmpty()) { //Do not forget to include the ! (NOT)
            OUT.writeUTF(textField.getText());
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"Assistant:"+textField.getText()+"\n");
        }    
    }
    catch (IOException c){
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

I hope to have been able to have helped you.